# date_parser format not being recognized for one of two similar files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to read a large .csv file that has date and time as the first column

I have tried stating the format with which the datetime column needs to be read

```
def csv_to_df(file_path):
    dateparse = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, skipinitialspace = True, parse_dates = ['Time'], date_parser=dateparse, index_col="Time")
    return df  
filename = 'somefilename'
df_sr = csv_to_df('somefilepath' + filename + '.csv')
```

For some files, it works and I can move on to the step to plot graphs. For others, I get the following error message:

ValueError: time data '7/27/19 1:30' does not match format '%m-%d-%y %H:%M' (match)

Comment: error show you that you have date `'7/27/19 1:30'` so it can't match to `'%m-%d-%y %H:%M'` . You may have to read date as string, make corrections in datafarame and then convert to datetime. Or your parser has to check date with two different formats and catch error - `try/except`.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve] next time. You would have found the reason for your fault yourself, which is exactly why this is required.

Answer (score 1):

You have date `'7/27/19 1:30'` which does not match format `'%m-%d-%y %H:%M'` so you have to create more complex parser

```
def dateparse(x):
    try:
      result = pd.to_datetime(x, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    except:
      result = pd.to_datetime(x, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    return result

def csv_to_df(file_path):
    return pd.read_csv(..., date_parser=dateparse)
```

---

If you know that file uses one format but you have to set it individally for every file then you can add argument `datetime_format` to your function

```
def csv_to_df(file_path, datetime_format):
    dateparse = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format=datetime_format)
    return pd.read(...)
```

---

**EDIT:** you can also try module [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which should recognize date in different formats.

Comment: Is there a way to pass that format while creating the dataframe? I made the dataframe from a few thousand ascii files

Comment: you can always use variable - ie. `my_format` - in parser `dateparse = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format=my_format)` and then you can assign different format before you load data.

Answer (score 0):

if you date format is like '7/27/19 1:30' where year is 0-99 and without seconds you can try:

```
pd.to_datetime(x, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from dateutil import parser

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x : parser.parse(x))
```

you don't need to specify any format it allows to have different format and convert it in best way

```
print(parser.parse("27/7/19 1:30"))
# 2019-07-27 01:30:00

print(parser.parse("7/27/19 1:30"))
# 2019-07-27 01:30:00

print(parser.parse("Aug 28 2019 12:00AM"))
# 2019-08-28 00:00:00
```